# CommunityToolkit.Maui.Markup nuget package installs with compilation errors

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, maui, nuget-package, markup

Freshly installed nuget package in a fresh maui app project and it's missing a field or property called CounterBtn. I don't know what type it's supposed to be.

`The name 'CounterBtn' does not exist in the current context`

I tried to follow a youtube tutorial of how to use markup instead of xaml for maui.

Comment: I included an image however it's not been added to the post without informing me. I guess that was a bug. 
Here is the image:
<https://imgur.com/a/zcaPgRc>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my own fault. I didn't understand how the xaml.cs script was referencing the xaml parent script, and I had commented out the xaml code for the button.

Comment: You could delete your question and answer.